# Getting a "Login failed for user Microsoft\my@email.com" without having specified username in connection string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-connection, dbcontext

I'm struggling with an issue that seemingly came out of nowhere for me.

I'm using A DbContext with a connection string specified from a Web.config file. It was working fine, until it wasn't.  Now when I run my integration tests, my DbContext can't save changes and I get the "Login failed for user Microsoft\my@email.com" exception, where Microsoft\my@email.com is the email I have registered with my Microsoft account.   The strange thing is is that my SQL server uses Windows authentication, and I don't specify a username to be used anywhere in my connections.  I've debugged and verified that my context's connection string is accurate, so I have no idea why my connection would be attempting to connect with a username I never set, from an account that I don't link to anywhere in my code.  I can also connect to my localhost db fine thru SSMS using Windows auth, so I know that isn't the issue.  I don't recall explicitly changing anything, however something obviously got switched somewhere.  See my connection string below.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Is there another place a connection might be attempting to pull information from, or something I may be missing in regards to my connection?  Any guidance here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: With current information, probably only wild guess can be given to you. I advice you to go step by step using debug and check from where the problem is coming.

Comment: What is the user account under which your process is running? That might give you a clue of where the account is derived from.

Comment: Needed to be running Visual Studio as admin.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to run Visual Studio as an administrator in order for my program to have access to localhost, and the user it used was coming from my Microsoft account.  Hope this helps someone else running in to this!